# Unzip files that contain chinese characters

Tags: java

I have a zip file.It contains some files.Files contain chinese characters so I used

```
   ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath), BUFFER_SIZE),
            Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")
    );
```

......

```
   FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(uncompressedFileName);
                while (zipStream.available() > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(zipStream.read());
                }
```

Extraction runs succesfully.After that  I want to use encodingDetect method to find encoding but now service is not running.It returns nomatch. If I send files directly to service,The service is running.It find charset properly like UTF-8.

I guess  that `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")`extract files but format is corrupted.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you mean file **names** contain chinese characters? Please describe in a very detailed way how do you call encodingDetect?

Comment: File name and file content contain chinese characters.EncodingDetect method is used to find charset.It runs properly if I send files(not zip) directly to method but if I send files after extraction method cannot find charset

Comment: Please describe what "very detailed" mean to you

Comment: I cannot find charset of files if I extract files from zip.

Comment: That's what "very detailed" mean to you? Okay... We don't use the same words, so it's hard to follow each other. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Charset of the file names in the zip. UTF-8 raises an error (the file names are evidently not in UTF-8), as UTF-8 requires as special format for the multi-byte sequences, and evidently there are wrong "multibyte" sequences.

ISO-8859-1 is a single byte enconding, accepting garbage.

What you should do is to try the small number of [Chinese Charsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_encoding), so the file name strings are filled correctly. Java String contains Unicode, so can hold any Charset. The help from someone talking Chinese probably would make sense.

And then try writing files with those names. If not successful on your PC, you must use artificial file names, maybe [transliteration from Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin).

A translation table from original Chinese file name to actual file name may be created
as UTF-8 text file, maybe with a BOM, '\uFEFF` at the begin-of-file.

Comment: Thank you very much.I updated my code.Filename is UTF-8 and I extract files properly.But the file contains Chinese characters.What I understand that I have to write file with  proper encoding to be able to find encoding  on encodingDetect method.

Comment: No the file itself is just binary data. If it represents (Chinese) _text_ in some unknown encoding, I would expect encodingDetect to find that encoding. And _then_ you have the encoding/charset to read it or convert it to UTF-8 text.

Answer (score 1):

ISO-8859-1 charset most definitely does not support Chinese language. Use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1

Comment: I mean, you need to use the right charset. If Chinese is involved we know that the right charset isn't iso-8859-1. But we have no indication whether it is utf-8 or any Chinese-friendly charset

Comment: When I used utf-8, extraction is not running.I cannot extract zip files

Comment: You can try not to send charset param at all. It will use your system default charset